# Cosmos DB data modelling to optimize search

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, data-modeling

I watched [this video](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/build-2019-best-practices-for-azure-cosmos-db-data-modeling-partitioning-and-rus/) on data modelling in Cosmos DB.

In the video, it is explained that if you can model your data such that your most common queries are in partition queries, then you can minimize RUs, which in turn minimizes cost and maximizes performance.

The example used in the video is a blogging system. They showed that by moving things around such that Blog Posts and Comments are stored as separate entities in the same collection all partitioned by `blogId` they could achieve a low RU for a common query.

They then showed that searching for all blog posts by a specific user, being a cross partition query, is very expensive. So they then duplicate all blog post data and add each blog post as a separate entity to the users collection, which is already partitioned by `userId`. Searching for posts by a user is now cheap. The argument is storage is much cheaper than CPU time so this is a fine thing to do.

My question is: do I continue to follow this pattern when I want to make more things efficiently searchable? For example, I want to be able to search on blog topic (of which there could be many per blog post), a discrete blog rating, and so on.

I feel like extending this pattern for each search term is unsustainable. In these cases, do I just have to live with high RU searches or is there some clever way of making things efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essentially comes down to knowing whether the cost of using change feed to copy data from one container to another is less than the cost of doing cross-partition queries. This requires knowing the access patterns of your application and also requires measuring the average cost of these queries versus the cost of using change feed to make another copy. Change feed consumes 2 RU/s when it polls the container, then 1 RU for each 1Kb or less read from the source container and ~8 RU for each 1Kb or less insert on target container depending on your index policy. Multiply that by the rate at which data is inserted or updated. Then calculate this per day or per month to compare cost.

If what you're looking for is to do free text search on your data, you may want to look at using Azure Search. This is simpler than using the approach using change feed, but Azure Search can be quite expensive as well.

Comment: I’m surprised that the only way (staying within cosmos db) of enabling efficient search on multiple attributes is to copy the data to multiple collections each partitioned by a different attribute of interest. Maybe I just need to let go of my RDBMS mindset but this is a tough pill to swallow.

Comment: @ChechyLevas - you wouldn't be copying *all data* - just the minimum needed for your queries. And an RDBMS doesn't make this issue disappear, as you still have to design your tables and foreign keys to optimize your queries (as well as joins; often you'll find that RDBMS-based modelling has similar denormalizing to optimize for specific query patterns - even moreso when getting into warehouse modeling). You'll find the same modeling technique with, say, Azure Table Storage.